# How to clear Android browser's localStorage?

Tags: browser, htc-evo

I've got an HTC Evo Design 4G (Android 2.3.4), and I can't figure out how to clear localStorage in the browser. Clearing the cache, history, form data and everything else doesn't do it. Resetting the browser to default settings doesn't do it. The website (served from the local network) doesn't show up in Website settings either.

The only thing that does work is deleting ALL data from the phone by resetting it to factory defaults.

Is there an easier option, and how come this isn't done as part of clearing cache which should "clear locally cached content and databases"?

Comment: Thanks for this. Just solved a clients problem. It's seems VERY annoying that it just can't be cleared.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try: `Settings` → `Applications` → `Manage Applications` → Select `Browser` ("`All apps`" tab) → `Clear Data`. This would delete all the data belonging to the app. Quite like a factory reset, but just for that app.

Be careful while using this. Make sure you select the correct application (Its called '`Browser`' some phones and '`Internet`' on some) in the `All apps` list.

**You can accidentally delete your contacts and other important stuff if you are not careful**

Comment: Thanks, that works! Instead of Browser I have "Internet", I guess it might be Sprint's way of making it more "accessible".

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this when Browser had way too many megabytes of data.

If you're root you can remove the localstore files *without* clearing all browser data (bookmarks etc.) by using Ghost Commander or similar app, or adb shell, to remove the localstore files from /data/data/com.android.browser/app_databases.

Answer (score 1):

This question came up in Google search for a generic Android/Chrome local storage removal/reset question so here's an answer for how it is done in..

**Chrome 68**

- With browser open tap 3 dots 'menu icon' (top right)
- tap 'settings'
- tap 'site settings'
- tap 'storage'

*to clear individual site storage*

- tap 'search icon' find the domain you want cleared
- tap on domain
- tap 'delete icon' (garbage can) to remove 'stored data'
- confirm by tapping 'clear all'

*to clear local storage on all sites*

- tap 'clear site storage'
- confirm by tapping 'clear all'